# How can I deploy an i18n application to cpanel?

Tags: php, angular, deployment, localization, cpanel

I always mess up something, the localized language index.html does not find the main javascript files, nor the images, although they are right in front.

What is the procedure of a deploy? My folders are "en-US" and "fr-FR"

I tried changing some cPanel settings but I'm not so qualified in it, and it already ate 5 hours of my time.